# Est-il possible d'utiliser « parce » sans « que » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, locutions

Je me suis récemment posé la question : est-il possible d'utiliser « parce » tout seul ?
Je veux dire qu'on l'emploie toujours suivi de « que » dans « parce que » mais y a-t-il des cas où il est employé tout seul ou accompagné d'un autre mot ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Le Wiktionnaire dit que non](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parce). La locution « parce que » est [l'évolution de « par ce que »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parce_que#.C3.89tymologie) ou « pour ce que ». Ces deux mots n'ont été contractés que dans cette expression.